# Does an Array of a large class (with lots of unused methods) take more time to compute than with smaller classes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class-method

I was wondering the following thing:

I have an array of a "Projectile" class for a 2d game. Every Projectile works a little bit different and thus needs different methods. Im beginning to realize that the "Projectile" class could explode and take up to 100-200 differnt methods. When looping through the Array, most methods wont be needed for most projectiles so i was wondering if the runtime will slow down because of the large amount of 'possible' methods to compute. Or if the Memory will explode with a large array using large Classes. Im using Javascript and trying to optimize the Program but asking generally.

Now, I know that it makes sense to inherit the Projectile Class in smaller classes (which is what im doing for other reasons anyways) but the question still stands. Or, what is the smartest way to go about this problem, if it's a problem at all?

Comment: If nothing's calling the methods, there's nothing to "compute". Try the game and see how it works, then worry about performance issues later.

Comment: Having this many (unused) methods for the behavior of projectiles indicates flaw in your code design. You may want to read about entity-component-systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating many instances of your big class won't increase the memory usage much, because all of the methods are attached to the instances prototypes, so it's only one prototype (holding the methods) referenced by multiple instances.

Here is a demonstration:

```js
class BigClass {
  method1() {}
  method2() {}
  method3() {}
  // ...
}

const instance1 = new BigClass;
const instance2 = new BigClass;

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(BigClass.prototype));
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(instance1) === BigClass.prototype); // true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(instance1) === Object.getPrototypeOf(instance2)); // true
console.log(instance1.method1 === instance2.method1); // true
```

When you have a constructor, the properties are attached to the instances themselves, increasing the memory usage proportionally to the number of instances.

Demo:

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    this.arg1 = arg1;
    this.arg2 = arg2;
    this.arg3 = arg3;
  }
}

const instance1 = new SomeClass({});
const instance2 = new SomeClass({});

console.log(instance1.arg1 === instance2.arg1); // false

// Note: that is not true when you pass an argument as a reference
const obj = {};

const instance3 = new SomeClass(obj);
const instance4 = new SomeClass(obj);

// In that case, obj is shared between the two instances

console.log(instance3.arg1 === instance4.arg1); // true

instance3.arg1.test = 'value';
console.log(instance4.arg1); // { test: 'value' }
```